# $.ajax work fine on localhost but not on online server : 500 internal server error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i used ajax to send data to the server, it works fine on localhost but i test the code on an online server it return error 500.

How to solve this?

```
$('#btn_publier').click(function (e) {
  var formdata = new FormData(document.getElementById('post'));
  var file_data = $('#IMG_CDV').prop('files')[0];

  formdata.append('file', file_data);

  $.ajax({
    url: '../wp-content/plugins/Carnet_voyages/publier.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: formdata,
    dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (result, statut) { // success est toujours en place, bien sûr !
      if (result != "") {
        alert(result);
        location.reload();
      }
    },
    error: function (resultat, statut, erreur) {
      alert(erreur);
    }
  });

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: A 500 error means the issue is in your PHP code. Check the response text or your server logs and hopefully there will be an error you can diagnose.

Comment: Can't diagnose a server error by looking at client side code

Comment: Also should be using proper wordpress ajax endpoint...not going into `wp-content/plugins`

Comment: jquery.js:9664 POST http://xxxx/wp-content/plugins/Carnet_voyages/publier.php 500 (Internal Server Error) ; this is the text on log console returned

Comment: Browser has no idea what happened on server. All it knows is  server returned a 500 status indicating something went wrong there. If error display is activated in the server code, look at actual response body in dev tools network. Server error logs will tell you also

Comment: Please paste your error.log here.

Answer (score 1):

Error 500 usually occurs from Internal Server Errors

Try
1. reloading the page,
2. Clear your browser's cache,
3. Delete your browser's cookies,
4. Troubleshoot as a 504 Gateway Timeout error instead,
or directly considering proper configuration of your online server or site administrators

Knowing its possible causes also help:

1)  A Permissions Error. In most cases, a 500 Internal Server Error is due to an incorrect permission on one or more files or folders. In most of those cases, an incorrect permission on a PHP and CGI script is to blame. These should usually be set at 0775 (-rwxr-xr-x).

```
2) A PHP Timeout. If your script connects to external resources and those resources timeout, an HTTP 500 error can occur. Timeout rules, or better error handling in your script, should help if this is the cause of the 500 error.

3) A Coding Error in .htaccess. While not as common, be sure to check that your site's .htaccess file is properly structured.
```

Comment: in my case, i think my problem is 2) because i have to upload file from local resource to the server ; that's perfectly work when testing on localhost but not online ! Now, i don't have permission on server configuration , i will contact administrators but have you any idea what to modify on the server?

Comment: The code I see is fine. I can't say for now until you've received a response from the administrators. Probably it could an error they frequently encounter.  For the mean time, ask yourself these questions 

1) Are you missing any javascript plugin files or the plugin files path is not defined you faced the 500 internal server error.
2) Hosting server is Case Sensitive check the Variable values.
3) If you move to ajax before alerting the flow.

Comment: well i'm not well experienced with ajax ,but i don't come to understand is if the script have worked on local what is the problem then ? local and externat server architecture aren't simular ?